# get current time in extjs view

Tags: date, extjs, time

i have a extjs view file, here it is:

```
                {
                    xtype       : 'timefield',
                    name        : 'startTime',
                    minValue    : '00:00',
                    maxValue    : '24:00',
                    value       : '08:00',
                    format      : 'H:i',
                    increment   : 30,
                    width       : 80,
                    hidden      : true
                }
```

but i want to show current date, i have code to show current date `value: new Date(yr, mt, (dt))` but i don't know how to show time.. i used `value: new Date(ht)` then `value  : new Date(th)` but they don't work. any solution for me?
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To show the current time you can simply set the value in your timefield to `new Date()` and it will display it in the specified format. This can be shown [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/j6i). It also uses a field label to display the current date using:

`fieldLabel: Ext.Date.format(new Date(), 'Y-m-d')`

You could show the current date elsewhere (not in a field label) but the logic remains the same.

Comment: thanks.. i just edit `Ext.Date.format(new Date(), 'Y-m-d')` became `Ext.Date.format(new Date(), 'H')`. thank u so much @MonicaOlejniczak